# why should i declare handle["/"] at request handling object in http server with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have encountered with this nice [tutorial  to node.js](http://nodebeginner.org/).
There is some example there :

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {}
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

Why do I need   `handle["/"]` what is it good for?

he says there :

> As you can see, it's really simple to map different URLs to the same request handler: by adding a key/value pair of "/" and requestHandlers.start, we can express in a nice and clean way that not only requests to /start, but also requests to / shall be handled by the start handler.

why that solve any problem and what is the problem at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function binded to handle["/"] will be called when somebody visits yoursite.com, and handle["/start"] will be called for visits to yoursite.com/start

The author is trying to build a server that will display different things based on routes (urls).